# How to make a boolean array by checking if the items in an array is in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, boolean

I'm trying to find every item in an numpy array `arr` that's also in an arbitrary list `lst` and replace them, but while `arr > 0` will generate a boolean array for easy masking, `arr in lst` only works with all() or any() which isn't what I need.

Example input: array `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, list `[2, 4, 6, 8]`

Output: array `(1, 0, 3, 0, 5)`

I managed to get the same result with for loops:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] in lst:
        arr[i] = 0
```

Just wondering if there are other ways to do it that set arrays apart from lists.

Comment: Can you show the example input and output? Then anyone can help you

Comment: Added the examples and made the question more specific, hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
a = np.array((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
lst = [2, 4, 6, 8]
a[np.isin(a, lst)] = 0
```

Gives you an `a` of:

```
array([1, 0, 3, 0, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `lst` and still use numpy's indexing.

```py
for element in lst:
  arr[arr == element] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one also.

```py
arr = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
lst = [2, 4, 6, 8]

new_arr = tuple('Replace With Anything' if a in lst else a for a in arr)
print(new_arr)
```